# How to pass a command line to Symfony Process component

Tags: php, symfony, process, symfony-process

I've tried to pass the following command line to Symfony Process component according to Symfony documentation:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(['cat crons/* | crontab -']);
$process->run();
```

and also the following:

```
$process = new Process(['cat crons/*', '|', 'crontab -']);
```

and:

```
['cat crons/*', '|', 'crontab', '-']
```

but it doesn't work, it rises an exception:

```
 The command "'cat /var/www/config/crontab/* | crontab -'" failed.       
                                                                          
  Exit Code: 127(Command not found)                                       
                                                                          
  Working directory: /var/www                                             
                                                                          
  Output:                                                                 
  ================                                                        
                                                                          
                                                                          
  Error Output:                                                           
  ================                                                        
  sh: exec: line 1: cat /var/www/config/crontab/* | crontab -: not found
```

Have anyone a solution please ?

Comment: You want to pipe the output of `cat /var/www/config/crontab/*` to `crontab -`, right?

Comment: You can pipe input/output with the Process component. But before that, have you tried `['cat crons/*', '|', 'crontab', '-']`?

Comment: Yes that's right :-) 
I've tried too : ```['cat crons/*', '|', 'crontab', '-']```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#using-features-from-the-os-shell) says:

> Using an array of arguments is the recommended way to define commands. This saves you from any escaping and allows sending signals seamlessly (e.g. to stop processes while they run):
>
> ```
> $process = new Process(['/path/command', '--option', 'argument', 'etc.']);
> $process = new Process(['/path/to/php', '--define', 'memory_limit=1024M', '/path/to/script.php']);
> ```
>
> If you need to use stream redirections, conditional execution, or any other feature provided by the shell of your operating system, you can also define commands as strings using the `fromShellCommandline()` static factory.

So if you are providing your command as an array, you *do not* put the entire command into a single array argument. And, if you are trying to do things like redirects, you do not use an array *at all*.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = Process::fromShellCommandLine('cat crons/* | crontab -');
try {
    $process->run();
} catch (ProcessFailedException $e) {
    ...
}
```